# How can I update a file to the head revision on SVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm trying to understand SVN coming from git. I have performed an update but one of my files still has an exclamation mark.

[image]

Is the exclamation mark there because I changed it and it's different from the file on the repository? And I want to overwrite the working copy and for that file to be the version at the head of the repository, how can I do that in SVN, either with the command line or `tortoisesvn`?

I'm following this [tutorial](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-update.html) but it doesn't mention this.

Comment: That's not really a tutorial (though it's quite decent documentation anyway). Please check [Icon Overlays](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html#tsvn-dug-wcstatus-1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The file contains local modifications. Therefore, it is marked as (M)ofidied.
2. When you run `svn update`, Subversion does not revert local changes. It merges modifications incoming from the repository with your local modifications when possible (or raises a conflict which you need to solve manually). Running `svn update` will never remove your local uncommitted modifications.
3. If you want to clean up your local modifications, you need to run `svn revert` or a corresponding **Revert** command of TortoiseSVN. **Note that this operation is irreversible - use `svn revert` with caution!**
   [image]

Comment: Thank you! Revert was just what I needed. Was confused that when I ran update it seemed to complete without any issue and only after I noticed the exclamation mark.